# Obtain ServiceDeploymentId in TrackingParticipant

Tags: persistence, workflow-foundation-4, tracking

In WF4, I've created a descendant of TrackingParticipant. In the Track method, record.InstanceId gives me the GUID of the workflow instance.

I'm using the SqlWorkflowInstanceStore for persistence. By default records are automatically deleted from the InstancesTable when the workflow completes. I want to keep it that way to keep the transaction database small.

This creates a problem for reporting, though. My TrackingParticipant will log the instance ID to a reporting table (along with other tracking information), but I'll want to join to the ServiceDeploymentsTable. If the workflow is complete, that GUID won't be in the InstancesTable, so I won't be able to look up the ServiceDeploymentId.

How can I obtain the ServiceDeploymentId in the TrackingParticipant? Alternately, how can I obtain it in the workflow to add it to a CustomTrackingRecord?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get the ServiceDeploymentId in the TrackingParticipant. Basically the ServiceDeploymentId  is an internal detail of the SqlWorkflowInstanceStore.

I would either set the SqlWorkflowInstanceStore to not delete the worklow instance upon completion and do so myself at some later point in time after saving the ServiceDeploymentId with the InstanceId.

An alternative is to use auto cleanup with the SqlWorkflowInstanceStore and retreive the ServiceDeploymentId when the first tracking record is generated. At that point the workflow is not complete so the original instance record is still there.

Comment: I added an insert/update trigger to the InstancesTable that copies the Id and ServiceDeploymentId to a new table when ServiceDeploymentId is non-NULL and was inserted or changed.